Comparison theorem with inequalities (ODE)
I have the following question. Suppose $y_1$ and $y_2$ satisfies the following inequalities
$$y_1' < f_1(t, y_1(t))   \hspace{2 cm} y_2' < f_2(t, y_2(t)),$$
and $y_1(0) < y_2(0)$ but $f_1 > f_2$. Then can I conclude that $y_1 > y_2$ ? I tried to integrate and then I used the first estimates but I stucked here because I do not know how to use the second one. Please, can you help me?

Should the LHS of your inequalities be derivatives?

Also, here is a related question with some slightly modified assumptions that may be helpful

Yes, I am sorry. I forgot the derivatives on the LHS. I ahve read that question but I do not know how I can use it since in my case I have the inquealities in both the differential conditions

If $y_1(0) < y_2(0)$ then $y_1>y_2$ is surely wrong.

I think that too. The question comes from Tao's book on dispersive PDE. In the appendix B, he shows uniqueness of ground state. In the second part of lemma B.10, he proves that $\partial_t^2 u_y(t) + \frac{d-1}{t} \partial_t u_y(t) < 0$, where $u_y(t)$ is stricly decreasing. He says that one can use a comparison principle to get that $u_y$ is negative. So I thought that I can prove $u_y < \partial_t u_y < 0$. But if I do that, I need a comparison principle like the one in my question.

This makes no sense, not even in the equality case. So system 1 grows faster than system 2, and solution 1 starts below solution 2. What is there to prevent the solutions crossing?
Or let's construct a counter-example on the positive quadrant. Set $f_1(y)=2y$, $f_2(y)=y$, so that $f_1>f_2$ on the selected domain. As functions select $y_1(t)=e^t$ and $y_2(t)=1+e^{t/2}$.
Or if the initial inequality was the wrong way, we can select $y_1(t)=1+e^{t/4}$ and $y_2(t)=e^{t/2}$, which will also cross.

Yes, I was thinking about the crossing solutions too. Thank you for your example.
